# What is the biggest non-integer float value in Python?

Tags: python

Floats, in any language or platform, have limited precision. They must have a finite number of digits "after the comma" when written in base 2, and that number is bound by the number of digits used as the mantissa (see [floating-point arithmetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) for more information).

When you get float numbers of increasing values, there comes a point where you can't write enough digits for any to end up after the comma - I suppose this may be false for a very long mantissa and very short exponent implementation, but I doubt it exists in practice.

How can I calculate that number, the largest `float` number `b`, such that `b.is_integer()` is False?

I'm asking for a calculation which would work on any implementation of Python, so presumably using `sys.float_info`.

(obviously, inf doesn't count)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case for this?

Comment: @SvenMarnach a possible implementation of `int_bigger_than_biggest_float_ever//.5` to return the same thing as `the_same_int*2`. When the float denominator is small enough, its inverse is bigger than the float limit I'm looking for in the question, so it can be resolved losslessly as a simple multiplication of integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The largest finite non-integer float value would be `math.nextafter(sys.float_info.radix**(sys.float_info.mant_dig - 1), 0)`:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: import math

In [3]: math.nextafter(sys.float_info.radix**(sys.float_info.mant_dig - 1), 0)
Out[3]: 4503599627370495.5
```

`sys.float_info.mant_dig` is the number of significant figures in a `float` value in the floating-point representation's radix.

`sys.float_info.radix**(sys.float_info.mant_dig - 1)` is the smallest number where all these significant figures would be before the decimal point as a float, and the `math.nextafter` call produces the largest value where one of these significant figures is after the decimal point. (`sys.float_info.radix**(sys.float_info.mant_dig - 1)` happens to be an int rather than a float, but that's fine.)

Comment: `.hex()` also shows it nicely: `0x1.fffffffffffffp+51`